# what is faster, du or stat?

Tags: bash, du, stat

Which goes faster on Linux/Unix?

```
du -b file.dat
```

or:

```
stat -c %s file.dat
```

Comment: Isn't this something you could Just Try™?

Comment: I have tried it, and the results are sometimes *inconsistent*, that's why I'm asking other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems du is slightly faster in this example.

```
$ time bash -c 'for ((i=1; i<1000;i++)); do stat -c %s file1 >/dev/null; done'
real    0m3.588s
user    0m0.120s
sys 0m0.344s

$ time bash -c 'for ((i=1; i<1000;i++)); do du -b file1 >/dev/null; done'
real    0m3.161s
user    0m0.092s
sys 0m0.360s
```

But personally, I'd prefer to use stat, because most people use stat to retrieve basic information of a single file. So it's more likely stat will be optimized for such jobs in future.

Comment: Here is stat: "real 0m2.183s" and here is du: "real 0m1.940s".. My file is 500MB [taken from /dev/zero], so I guess du _is_ faster..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `time` command to find out:

```
time du -b file.dat
time stat -c %s file.dat
```